# How Can I Make Oracle Query Sort Order Dynamic?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle10g, sql-order-by, dynamicquery

I have a Oracle procedure inside a package like this

```
PROCEDURE getEmployee
(
  pinLanguage               IN    VARCHAR2,
  pinPage                   IN    NUMBER,
  pinPageSize               IN    NUMBER,
  pinSortColumn             IN    VARCHAR2,
  pinSortOrder              IN    VARCHAR2,
  poutEmployeeCursor        OUT   SYS_REFCURSOR
)
AS
BEGIN
    OPEN poutEmployeeCursor FOR
    SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, USERNAME, FULL_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH, EMP.GENDER_ID, GEN_TR.GENDER, EMP.WORK_TYPE_ID, WT_TR.WORK_TYPE, SALARY, EMAIL, PROFILE_IMAGE,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID ASC) RN

      FROM EMPLOYEES EMP
      INNER JOIN GENDERS GEN ON EMP.GENDER_ID = GEN.GENDER_ID
      LEFT JOIN GENDERS_MLD GEN_TR ON GEN.GENDER_ID = GEN_TR.GENDER_ID AND GEN_TR.LANGUAGE = pinLanguage
      INNER JOIN WORK_TYPES WT ON EMP.WORK_TYPE_ID = WT.WORK_TYPE_ID
      LEFT JOIN WORK_TYPES_MLD WT_TR ON WT.WORK_TYPE_ID = WT_TR.WORK_TYPE_ID AND WT_TR.LANGUAGE = pinLanguage
    )
    WHERE RN BETWEEN (((pinPage - 1) * pinPageSize) + 1) AND (pinPage * pinPageSize);
END;
```

I need to make the sort order of the above query dynamic

If I pass the text **FullName** to **pinSortColumn** parameter, it need to sort **FULL_NAME** column

If I pass the text **DateOfBirth** to **pinSortColumn** parameter, it need to sort **DATE_OF_BIRTH** column

If I pass the text **Gender** to **pinSortColumn** parameter, it need to sort **GEN_TR.GENDER** column

I can pass the text **asc** or **desc** to **pinSortOrder** parameter and the query need to be sorted accordingly.
Can you please help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use separate order by for `asc` and `desc` as following:

```
ORDER BY 
CASE pinSortOrder WHEN 'asc' THEN
    CASE pinSortColumn 
      WHEN 'FullName' THEN FULL_NAME 
      WHEN 'DateOfBirth' THEN to_char(DATE_OF_BIRTH,'yyyymmddhh24miss')
      WHEN 'Gender' THEN GEN_TR.GENDER   
    END
END,
CASE pinSortOrder WHEN 'desc' THEN
    CASE pinSortColumn 
      WHEN 'FullName' THEN FULL_NAME 
      WHEN 'DateOfBirth' THEN to_char(DATE_OF_BIRTH,'yyyymmddhh24miss')
      WHEN 'Gender' THEN GEN_TR.GENDER   
    END
END DESC
```

Let's say you have passed `pinSortColumn` as `FullName` and `pinSortOrder` as `asc` then order by clause will be `ORDER BY FULL_NAME, NULL DESC` (please note that default order will be asc so I have not write it in the code. Query will be ordered by FULL_NAME in ascending manner)

Now, If you have passed `pinSortColumn` as `FullName` and `pinSortOrder` as `desc` then order by clause will be `ORDER BY NULL, FULL_NAME DESC`.

Null will not impact ordering.

I hope it is clear now.

Cheers!!

Comment: This is a good point but it always order in ASC. I cannot order in DESC.

Comment: `DESC` is there in the second case where we are comparing `pinSortOrder` with `desc`. You can try it. It was working smoothly in my local example

Comment: Sorry, I mean it sort `DESC` by default. But I cannot sort in `ASC`. Acording to your example, `DESC` is out of `CASE` statement. So I am also confused how it can sort in `ASC`?

Comment: I have updated my answer with description. Please check now

Comment: Thank you got your point and working. Now I have a new error when sorting **DATE_OF_BIRTH** `Error(316,51): PL/SQL: ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected CHAR got DATE`

Comment: Because `DATE_OF_BIRTH` is date and the other two fields are `CHAR`. You can try `to_char(DATE_OF_BIRTH,'yyyymmddhh24miss')` in `order by`. I have updated my answer accordingly. Please check now

Comment: I assume you need `CASE pinSortOrder WHEN 'desc' THEN ... ELSE NULL END`, otherwise you get an **ORA-06592: CASE not found while executing CASE statement** - but I am not sure about that.

Comment: No, It will return NULL if the condition is not satisfied

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
WHERE ...
ORDER BY 
   CASE pinSortColumn 
      WHEN 'FullName' THEN FULL_NAME 
      WHEN 'DateOfBirth' THEN DATE_OF_BIRTH
      WHEN 'Gender' THEN GEN_TR.GENDER   
   END;
```

However, I don't think you can use `ASC`, `DESC` is this way. You to create a dynamic query. For an `OPEN ... FOR ...` statement it is trivial:

```
sqlstr := 'SELECT * FROM (
      SELECT EMPLOYEE_ID, USERNAME, FULL_NAME, DATE_OF_BIRTH, EMP.GENDER_ID, GEN_TR.GENDER, EMP.WORK_TYPE_ID, WT_TR.WORK_TYPE, SALARY, EMAIL, PROFILE_IMAGE,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EMPLOYEE_ID ASC) RN

      FROM EMPLOYEES EMP
      INNER JOIN GENDERS GEN ON EMP.GENDER_ID = GEN.GENDER_ID
      LEFT JOIN GENDERS_MLD GEN_TR ON GEN.GENDER_ID = GEN_TR.GENDER_ID AND GEN_TR.LANGUAGE = :pinLanguage
      INNER JOIN WORK_TYPES WT ON EMP.WORK_TYPE_ID = WT.WORK_TYPE_ID
      LEFT JOIN WORK_TYPES_MLD WT_TR ON WT.WORK_TYPE_ID = WT_TR.WORK_TYPE_ID AND WT_TR.LANGUAGE = :pinLanguage
    )
    WHERE RN BETWEEN (((:pinPage - 1) * :pinPageSize) + 1) AND (:pinPage * :pinPageSize) 
    ORDER BY '

CASE pinSortColumn 
   WHEN 'FullName' THEN sqlstr := sqlstr || 'FULL_NAME ';
   WHEN 'DateOfBirth' THEN sqlstr := sqlstr || 'DATE_OF_BIRTH ';
   WHEN 'Gender' THEN sqlstr := sqlstr || 'GEN_TR.GENDER ';
END CASE;   
sqlstr := sqlstr || pinSortOrder;

OPEN poutEmployeeCursor FOR sqlstr USING pinLanguage, pinLanguage, pinPage, pinPageSize, pinPage, pinPageSize;
```

Not in case you run Oracle 12c or newer you can use the [Row Limiting Clause](https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1) instead of dealing with row number.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it is not working

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid all these duplicated `case`s. Multiply row number by `-1` when descending order is required:

```
order by 
    case pinSortOrder when 'desc' then -1 else 1 end * 
    row_number() over (
      order by case pinSortColumn when 'FullName'    then full_name     end, 
               case pinSortColumn when 'Gender'      then gender        end, 
               case pinSortColumn when 'DateOfBirth' then date_of_birth end)
```

**<sup>[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6972d8af582eab8497a576d3e6a9cbfc)</sup>**

Also this way you do not have to convert data the same type, no need to use `to_char`.